# File Download Primefaces not working and not make any action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

When click Download button , actionListener not working in case using ajax="false" status but when not using ajax="false" ,actionListener work  but not file downloading.

```
<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:tsc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<h:form>
<p:commandButton immediate="true" value="#{msgs.common_click_download}"
    icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" process="@this"
    rendered="#{manehHelperMB.isFileExist('/home/hazemelshenawy/111.txt')}">
    <p:fileDownload process="@this" contentDisposition="inline"
        value="#{fileDownloaderMB.downloadFile('/home/hazemelshenawy/111.txt')}" />
</p:commandButton>

 </h:form>
  </html>
```

this code java

```
public class FileDownloaderBean implements Serializable {
private DefaultStreamedContent file;

public DefaultStreamedContent downloadFile(String filePath) {
    if (filePath == null || filePath.isEmpty())
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    try {
        File fi = new File("/home/hazemelshenawy/111.txt");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fi);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        try {
            file = new DefaultStreamedContent(input,
                    externalContext.getMimeType(URLEncoder.encode(fi.getName(), "UTF-8")), fi.getName());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            CommonUtils.log(e);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        CommonUtils.log(e);
    }
    return file;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Which container do you use? Tomcat? Don't you have any error in server logs? Tomcat by default does not support passing arguments in el-expressions unless you make sure you've set the “el-impl-2.2.jar” or later properly.

Comment: Tomcat 8 , yes i don't have any error in server logs

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of an ActionListener attribute in p:commandButton when using with p:fileDownload, but you should have `ajax="false"` as stated in [Primefaces fileDownload Homepage](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml)

try to set the file path correctly. 
for e.g; In .xhtml file

```
rendered="#{manehHelperMB.isFileExist('D:\\home\\hazemelshenawy\\111.txt')}">
value="#{fileDownloaderMB.downloadFile('D:\\home\\hazemelshenawy\\111.txt')}"
```

and in java class

```
File fi = new File("D:\\home\\hazemelshenawy\\111.txt");
```

in addition you should have setter and getter methods:

```
public DefaultStreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }
public void setFile(DefaultStreamedContent file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
```